# Benefits of deploying using docker-compose

Tags: docker, deployment, docker-compose

If I am wrong at anything below, correct me pls.

Let's say I have simple frontend application (React, Vue, Angular, whatever) and then backend (Node.js or any RestAPI provider).

I am able to run both of them separately (not using docker), or both dockerized using docker-compose.

**Approach 1:** When not using docker, I need to deploy my application to 2 separate servers.

**Approach 2:** When using docker-compose, this allows me to deploy everything to a single server (like heroku). Frontend would be under default http port 80, backend would be for example under port 81.

I can already see that a huge benefit of approach 2) is that I don't need to pay for 2 hostings.

My questions are:

1. What is the speed comparison for both approaches of requests going from frontend to backend (I mean it for Server side rendering like Nuxt.js or Next.js). Is approach 2 going to be faster because it is on the same server?
2. What are the other pros and cons which I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: You probably want both halves served on the same host/port.  The easiest way to do this for this sort of 2-tier application is to compile the front-end application to static files, and then serve it from the back-end, though there are other approaches.  The performance difference using Docker or not probably won't be visible to your end users.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use SSR like Nuxt.js and thus I need Node.js server rather than static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't deploy your frontend and backend to the same server whether or not you use Docker and Docker Compose.

Using containers provides a mechanism by which you can package applications and publish these to registries and deploy them to other machines with a high degree of confidence that they will run on the other machines without change, now and in the future.

Without Docker, you need to provide scripts or some other form of deployment that can install the apps on other machines and, unless these other machines are perfect clones of your development host, you'll likely need to install other OS and software dependencies too.

So, Docker facilitates distribution and packaging of apps and it helps ensure multiple apps run on a single host without (unexpected) interactions between applications.

If you use containers but not Docker Compose, you need to provide scripts (or similar) that describes how your app (components: frontend|backend) interact and combine: which ports they use, their env environment (variables) etc. Docker Compose facilitates this and provides a convenient mechanism to describe how to combine the pieces into a coherent whole.

There are fully functional alternatives to Docker and Docker Compose but Docker and Docker Compose are widely used and you can assume that platform providers and prospective users of your app, are willing|able to use both of them.

Neither Docker nor Docker Compose add a performance overhead to your app. Both are primarily programmers of the control plane (so-called east-west) rather than your app's data plane (so-called north-south).

Running your app on a single server will almost always be more performant than running on multiple servers -- regardless of whether or not you use containers -- because you can avoid network latency which is a significant contribution to performance.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. This is what I needed. Appreciate :)